# Spring security intercept method shows error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-ldap, spring-security-acl

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd">

<bean id="messageBoardService" 
    class="com.service.MessageBoardServiceImpl">
    <security:intercept-methods>
    <security:protect 
        method="com.service.MessageBoardService.listMessages"
        access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_GUEST" />
    <security:protect 
        method="com.service.MessageBoardService.postMessage"
        access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:protect 
        method="com.service.MessageBoardService.deleteMessage"
        access="ROLE_ADMIN,IP_LOCAL_HOST" />
    <security:protect 
        method="com.service.MessageBoardService.findMessageById"
        access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_GUEST" />
    </security:intercept-methods>
</bean>
```

by executing the above lines of code its showing error

The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'

and getting red underline on  security intercept method tag

here are the list of jar files [image]

Comment: Post your full configuration (or at least include the header). You are mixing jars from different spring security versions (2.0.1 and 2.0.4) don't do that, use matching versions.

Comment: @M.Deinum I had added my headers as per your request. Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: Your root name space if security not beans. Remove the `security:` prefixes and add a `beans:` prefix to the `bean` elements as well as to `property` elements you have in your config. This is just how xml namespaces work (and isn't really spring related).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This header when added to the xml file. It works correct

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd">
```